# Groovy printf() output not as expected when 0 padded number is given

Tags: groovy

Why does the input `01234` return `668` in Groovy? What kind of conversion is taking place?

```
printf("%d", 01234)  //668
printf("%d", 0668)   //expecting ')', found '8' at line: 2, column: 17
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer literals with a leading zero are treated by the compiler as octal (base 8) so can only include the digits 0 to 7. That's why the second line gives a syntax error.

01234 octal is 668 decimal.

Similarly you can use `0x` for hexadecimal, e.g. `0x1234` represents 4660.

Answer (score 2):

01234 is an octal number, equal to 668 decimal.